# Create file at given relative path using python

Tags: python, file

My folder structure is: `C:/Users/Desktop/SampleTestFiles/ProjectFiles/ExceptionLogFiles/`

Using below code, I am trying to create file in `ExceptionLogFiles` folder if file `Exceptionlog.txt` does not exists and if file exists then open the file and write some text to the file. But for some reason code is unable to detect the relative path.

Please can anyone help me in correcting code:

```
fileDir = 'C:/Users/Desktop/SampleTestFiles'
filename = os.path.join(fileDir, '\..\ExceptionLogFiles\ExceptionLog.txt')


#print(filename) gives: C:/Users/Desktop/SampleTestFiles/../ExceptionLog.txt
if os.path.exists(filename):
    print(filename, 'exists')
    #Open file and write something to the file
    f = open(file, 'w')
    f.write("Exception Text")
    f.close()
else:
    print('file not exists')
    #Create File and Write something to the file.
    f = open(file, 'w+')
    f.write("Exception Text")
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

What you tried to do was kind of like this, in an addition-like fashion

```
(
C:/Users/Desktop/SampleTestFiles
+ 
.. (which is up one directory)
)
+ ExceptionLogFiles\ExceptionLog.txt
```

The "parenthesized" addition will actually resolve to `C:/Users/Desktop/`, and we add `ExceptionLogFiles\ExceptionLog.txt'` to that. So we'd be looking at: `C:/Users/Desktop/ExceptionLogFiles\ExceptionLog.txt'

However, even if you dropped the `..\` from your string, those backslashes don't become literal backslashes in a string without you escaping them.

Try this (and NOTE the backslashes are doubled so as to escape backslash, which is the escape character!)

```
fileDir = 'C:/Users/Desktop/SampleTestFiles'
filename = os.path.join(fileDir, 'ExceptionLogFiles\\ExceptionLog.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're looking for [normpath](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.path.html?highlight=normpath#os.path.normpath)

```
import os

fileDir = 'C:/Users/Desktop/SampleTestFiles'
filename = os.path.join(fileDir, '../ExceptionLogFiles/ExceptionLog.txt')
print(filename)
print(os.path.normpath(filename))
```

result:

```
C:/Users/Desktop/SampleTestFiles/../ExceptionLogFiles/ExceptionLog.txt
C:/Users/Desktop/ExceptionLogFiles/ExceptionLog.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "with open('path','a+') as f", whatever file exists or not,you can write something into it.